# Duplicate object on array when using .forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to push data using the .forEach function into an array of objects so that I could return a list of available feedbacks into the Administrator page for my portfolio but when they are pushed into the `feedback` array, it turns out that the objects from `d` get duplicated, but the weird part is that only the last object pushed that gets duplicated.

I've tried to reassign the array before fetching, using useState on `d`, using useState on feedback and on dataArray but it still returned the same.

Code:

```js
import styles from '../../styles/Home.module.css';
import { supabase } from '../../lib/supabase';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface s {
    session: any
}
interface dataObject {
    id: String,
    Name: String,
    Message: String,
}

const AdminPage = (props: s) => {
    let d = {} as dataObject
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [feedback, setFeedback] = useState<any>([{}]); 
    const dataArray:Array<any> = [];
    
    const getFeedback = async () => {
        try {
            setLoading(true)
            let {data, error, status} = await supabase
                .from('Feedback')
                .select('id, Name, Message')
            if (error && status !== 406) throw error;
            if (data) {
                data.forEach(element => {
                    console.log('Data: ', data)
                    const {id, Name, Message} = element;
                    d.id = id;
                    d.Name = Name;
                    d.Message = Message;
                    feedback.push(d);
                });
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // @ts-ignore
            alert(error.message)
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log('Feedback: ', feedback);
        }
    }
    const signOut = async () => {
        const { error } = await supabase.auth.signOut()
        if (error) throw error;
    }
    if (feedback !== [{}]) {
        feedback.forEach(element => {
            if (!element.id) return;
            dataArray.push(
            <div className={styles.card}>
                <div key={element.id}>
                 <p>{element.Name} says: &quot;{element.Message}&quot;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            )
        })
        console.log('DataArray: ', dataArray )
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {loading ? (
                'Loading Data...'
            ): (
                <div>
                    {dataArray.length == 2 ? (
                        <div className={styles.error}>
                            <p>No data available...</p>
                            </div>
                            ): (
                                <div>
                                    <h1>Feedback</h1>
                                    {dataArray}
                                </div>)
                            
                        }
                    <button className={styles.button_d} onClick={signOut}>Signout</button>
                    <button className={styles.button} onClick={getFeedback}>Get Feedback JSON</button>
                    </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AdminPage;
```

Console:

```
Data:  
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { id: "927c5399-7251-4139-8a31-5417f9383d06", Name: "Raul Perez", Message: "This is a test feedback to try out the brand new feedback feature from perezbueno.xyz!" }
​
1: Object { id: "d8981533-d629-4082-b45d-1ac9b758e73e", Name: "Hello World", Message: "deez nuts" }
​
length: 2
​
<prototype>: Array []
index.tsx:29:28
DataArray:  
Array(4) [ [], dispatchAction(), {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Array []
​
1: function dispatchAction()
​
2: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: "div", key: null, … }
​
3: Object { "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element"), type: "div", key: null, … }
​
length: 4
​
<prototype>: Array []
index.tsx:60:16
Feedback:  
Array(3) [ {}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object {  }
​
1: Object { id: "d8981533-d629-4082-b45d-1ac9b758e73e", Name: "Hello World", Message: "deez nuts" }
​
2: Object { id: "d8981533-d629-4082-b45d-1ac9b758e73e", Name: "Hello World", Message: "deez nuts" }
​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

Comment: [Link to the original issue](https://gitlab.com/perez-bueno/mainpage/-/issues/7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use setFeedback in order to update your state instead of feedback.push. Replace `feedback.push` with `setFeedback([...feedback,d])` and it should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

i think when change the state,should use setstate.
feedback.push(d) should change to

```
setfeedback(...feedback,d)
```

Comment: It returns an error: Expected 1 argument, but got 2

Comment: u can console and debug it ,i think in react component when change component should use setstate

Comment: I changed setFeedback(...feedback, d) to setFeedback([...feedback, d]) and it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: em thats right, sorry i forget the array[]